# Open File Dialog Initial directory

Tags: c#, wpf, dialog, directory

I have problem with InitialDirectory path i used part of code shown below. OpenDialog always show directory where i open file last time but i couldn't set new relative path.. I tried set absolute path but it didn't work also.

```
private static string path = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;

public static string OpenDialog()
    {
        // Create OpenDialog 
        var dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();

        // initial directory for OpenFileDialog need fix
        if(Directory.Exists(path))
        {
            dlg.InitialDirectory = path;
        } 

        dlg.RestoreDirectory = true;
```

Comment: var initialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path)

Comment: have you looked at the `OpenFileDialog method` you can set filer / default directory in code.. lookup the Method on MSDN
[Open File Dialog Initial Directory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.initialdirectory(v=vs.110).aspx) taken from a simple google search

Comment: i tried it but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

In your example, 'path' is being set to your .exe, which will cause if (Directory.Exists(path)) to fail, therefore, the dialog will open to the last known good directory, because InitialDirectory will not be set to the value that you want.  Try simply hard-coding a known good directory path first.  Or you could do something like this to fix it:

```
path = Directory.GetParent(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location).FullName;
```

Comment: did you try this?  it should fix your issue